# Getting the following error when adding youtube video to PHP array

Tags: php, html

Hi guys I am adding a YouTube video to a php array and I am getting the following error: 
syntax error , unexpected '425' (T_LNUMBER). expecting ')'
I have been trying to figure out all day how to resolve it but I have not been successful. Has anyone else ran into this problem or knows the resolution that could help me out.
The code is below :

```html
<object width="425" height="350" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/fKgG6guOLnw" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/fKgG6guOLnw"/></object>
```

Below I will show the whole array. If I remove the video from the array I have no problems with it.

```html
   array(

        'title' => 'Data Security for Educators',
    'text' => "<p>This is a brief description of the video.</p>
<a href=\"\documents\Data_Protection_Reminders.pdf\" target=\"_blank\">Companion Document<i class=\"fa fa-angle-right mag_left_small\"></i></a>"
           }
```

Comment: Please edit the question and include a [mre]. There is currently not enough information in the question to reproduce the problem statement.

Comment: You really need to add an example of how you are adding that to the array. However if I had to guess it's to do with quotes, ie you are using double quotes but because the attribute has double quotes you are getting the error. Basically try single quotes in the array assignment.

Comment: I added the example. If I remove the video from it it has no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just a syntax error you had an extra "/ before ending object see if it works now

```
<object width="425" height="350" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/fKgG6guOLnw" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/fKgG6guOLnw"></object>
```

Comment: unfortunetly that was not it still getting the same error :(
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '425' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ')'

Comment: PS : shockwave flash is no longer recommend to be used since most browsers have stopped supporting it.

Comment: Maybe you have some more syntax errors in your code

Comment: I shared the array. If I remove the video from it I have no problems with it.

Comment: You again have a lot of syntax errors basically the same